# How to make website available for all monitors?

Tags: html, css

I am using a code to make my website available for monitors starting from 800px
but when i enter a background image of width 800px it does not fill the page so i add higher width
but its not available for all monitors some other monitors show a horizontal scroll at the end of the page

Here's the code i am using:

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:800px;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;
}

#header {
    background-image:url(../imgs/header.png);
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -320px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    width: 1440px;
    height: 445px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

i hope someone helps me by giving me a right code to make the site available for all monitors:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its simple...to contain image in a div

use `background-size:cover` :)

```
#header {
   background-image:url(../imgs/header.png);
   background-size:cover /* here you go */
   -webkit-background-size: cover; /* vendor prefix */
   -moz-background-size: cover;/* vendor prefix */
   -o-background-size: cover;/* vendor prefix */
   position: absolute;
   margin-left: -320px;
   margin-top: -7px;
   width: 1440px;
   height: 445px;
   z-index: 1;
 }
```

**EDIT**

**Why scroll-bar appears:**??? because you have set :

```
    width: 1440px;
    height: 445px;
```

in the `#header`...change it to

```
width: 100%; /* this is the cause*/
height: 100%; /* this is the cause*/
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/w8vS2/)

Comment: i add it to body or the div id?

Comment: lemme try it and tell you:D

Comment: scroll bar still appears at the end of the page for small monitors:'(

Comment: giving solution fiddle...w8 :)

Comment: i checked it and added it
cool it works scroll bar dissappeared
but i had to make height:50%
because it was repeated
now the problem is the background image isnt containing the whole page in the small monitors !

Comment: can you contact me on skype?

Comment: skype is not going to be an option before 7hrs... :p
give me fiddle....u know how to make one???

Comment: np mate i added the other code 
    html,body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
    border:0;
    font-size:100%;
    height:100%;
    font:inherit;
    vertical-align:baseline;

you forgot to tell me to add it:D

Comment: @user3131996 : so is it working now??? in my fiddle...it was working even for small viewport....match the css against yours!! :)

Comment: yes i did and its working thanks
last question is for example the images and the fields
i make its width and height in px?
is this okay?

Comment: Its fixed for all monitors thanks alot but its not available for 1920px.

Answer (score 0):

I declared mine at the top of my css. Makes it the same on each page and it works. If the page gets longer, it gets longer to. What works for my anyway

```
html, header { 
  background-image:url('Background.png'); 
  background-size:100% 100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: thats it?and it will be available for all monitors?
what about after i add a background image i give it width and height in px too?

Comment: works on different sized monitors and different browsers for me, that is if you want the same background on every page that calls the CSS

Comment: i will add div classes with other backgrounds anything will happen?

Comment: I have my menu and footer with backgrounds defined in DIVS and they have backgrounds ok, as long as you define them in the CSS should work

Comment: any luck? you just need to stick it in CSS and its done no messing about

Comment: yes i added it and defined the width as 100%
works pretty good but tell me
do i have to add the width of search fields and other images(not background) as % too?or px is accepted?

Comment: Yea I have it set as px and % across the page and it all works fine for me